# Chrome Profiler: What happens during 'resource loading' phase of network request？

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, resource-loading

What chrome actually does when the status of `resource loading`？In the image, The network request all duration is `2.97s`, and `53.67ms` is `network transfer`, `2.92s` is the `resource loading`. What browser actually does when this `resource loading` status?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjyOk.png

Comment: Similar question posted by me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60972176/chrome-developer-tools-performance-profiling?noredirect=1#comment107871172_60972176

Comment: No answer there either until now :)

Answer (score 5):

Resource loading typically involves processing the received data.
you could find what the app actually does for 'resource loading' phase by opening the 'Main' section (Frames, Interactions, Main -..),
it would list function calls and the total time / self-time details.

Answer (score 0):

If your js thread is busy, the resource will wait until its idle, if you face a huge resouce loding time, checkout is there any long runing task in the Main section [image: like this]. Like this profiler an anonymous function occup main js thread, so the resource only avaliable after this function excuted